# Using GIMP, is there a way to fill an image that has transparency?

Tags: gimp, transparency, fill

For a given shape, I would like to fill it with the line color. However, using the fill bucket, the transparency on the inside of the image is still visible.

[image]

Double clicking with the fill bucket will remove the transparency from the inside, but it removes it from the outside of the shape as well. This creates a very pixelated shape.

[image]

Is there a way that I can preserve the transparency on the outside of the shape while filling completely on the inside? The example here is very simple with the oval, but the actual image I am working with is significantly more complex. It would take a very long time to fill by hand.

Answer (score 2):

The bucket fill tool will be able to fill similar colors with a given threshold. This can be used to fill open objects with the stroke color but it will not be able to discriminate inner or outer thresholds when the stroke had a semi-transparent border for anti-aliasing.

To overcome this we need some interim steps for desired results:

1. Use the magic wand select tool (*Fuzzy Select* in Gimp) rather than the bucket fill tool to select the object's inner area. Take care to set the threshold to `0` or very low values to avoid including outer portions of the stroke in the resulting selection. Do not feather the edges.

   [image]
2. Grow the selection (*Select > Grow*) with half the pixel width of the stroke. This will make our selection to be in the middle of the stroke's width:

   [image]
3. Use the bucket fill tool with setting to *Fill whole selection*. This will leave the outer parts of the stroke with the desired transparency.

   [image]

Note that on very complex objects you may need a considerable amount of RAM, and CPU power to calculate the path for the fuzzy fill area.